# Filtrando coleção de filhos em Entity Framework com Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho um caso onde preciso trazer todos os itens do objeto pai onde tenha uma determinada condição, exemplo:

```
ctx.Pai
    .Where(x=> x.Ativo == true)
    .Include(Filhos)
    .Where(TrazerApenasFilhosAtivos);
```

Já tentei utilizar com Any, mas olhando o SQL ele cria um Exists e não é isso que eu queria, queria trazer o pai ativo e todos os seus filhos também ativos.

Como fazer?

Comment: Você quer que ele apenas retorne os filhos e não o pai, certo?

Comment: Tenta `.Include(Filhos.Where(condicao));`

Comment: Se o que você quer é uma espécie de `Left Join`, com `Lambda` usando `Include` não é possível. Talvez sua solução seja com `Linq` (`from p in context.Pai ...`) ou `GroupJoin` com `Lambda`.

Comment: Exemplo de GroupJoin (Left Join): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JspxnEAE-M

Comment: Outro exemplo de Left Join, mas `Linq`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksGHiGg405M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
Pai
.Include(Filhos)
.Where(x => x.Ativo && !x.Filhos.Any(e => !e.Ativo));
```

---

EDIT: 
Pelo que entendi, você quer todos os filhos ativos:

```
pais.Where(e => e.Ativo)
            .Select(s => new Pai() { Filhos = s.Filhos.Where(e => e.Ativo).ToList() });
```

Comment: Mas assim ele me retorna todos os filhos independente de estarem ativos ou não, se houver qualquer incidência de um filho ativo.

Comment: @Kevin, no exemplo que fiz, ele trás apenas se tiver todos os filhos ativos (`!x.Filhos.Any(e => !e.Ativo)`). Fiz o inverso da lógica do `.Any()` que você tentou.

Comment: Ah, mas o que eu estou tentando trazer somente os filhos ativos, se houver inativo que não venha, mas os outros devem vir, sabe ?

Comment: Tá difícil de entender. Você quer que venham apenas os filhos que estão ativos naquele pai? Ou só o pai que tiver TODOS os filhos ativos?

Comment: @Kevin, fiz uma edição, dá uma olhada se atende.

Comment: Obrigado Filipe, deste modo funciona!

Comment: Por nada! Caso a resposta tenha atendido sua pergunta, é legal marcar como resposta para que ajude quem estiver precisando de uma solução parecida.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25975/discussion-between-kevin-and-filipe-oliveira).

Answer (score 1):

```
from pai in ctx.Pai
join filho in ctx.Filho on pai.Id equals filho.IdPai
where pai.Ativo && filho.Ativo
select pai
```

Caso retornar o pai não seja suficiente, você pode usar um `new` no `select` e montar o objeto do jeito que achar melhor ou apenas retornar o filho.

EDIT: imaginei mais ou menos como são as entidades, talvez tenha que fazer um pequeno ajuste na associação.

EDIT2: como o cenário é ManyToMany o uso de dois `from` pode resolver seu problema.

```
from pai in ctx.Pai
from filho in pai.Filhos
where filho.ativo && pai.ativo
select pai
```

Lembrando que o `select` deve ser o tipo que você quer que a query retorne, ou um novo tipo que você pode criar.

Comment: E no caso de Filho ser uma collection ?

Comment: Imagino que no Filho você tenha uma propriedade de navegação para o pai dele. Se tiver você pode usar ela, se não tiver acho que deveria ter. Como essa associação é feita?

Comment: É Many to Many:

Pai {
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Filho> Filhos {get;set;}
  public bool Ativo {get;set;}
}

Filho {
     public string Id {get;set;}
     public ICollection<Pai> Pais {get;set;}
     public bool Ativo {get;set;}
}

Comment: Ai você pode fazer dois from, vou editar a resposta original.

Comment: Funcionou certinho a Query, só que mesmo assim os itens filtrados não são retornados no objeto pai, tem alguma forma de fazer isso ou preciso dar um new ? Segue como ficou minha query:

var monitoramento = (
                from mon in _context.Monitoramentos
                from grupo in mon.Grupos
                where grupo.Status == StatusGrupo.Ativo && mon.Id == id && mon.Status == StatusMonitoramento.Monitorando
                select new { mon, grupo}).FirstOrDefault();

se no final eu selecionar apenas mon, todos os grupos dele virão sem estar filtrados.

Comment: Talvez você possa setar o grupo no mon dentro do new. mon.Grupos = groupos.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25969/discussion-between-kevin-and-hokos).